# Getting Access 2016 (Data and Forms) into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-migration-assi, ms-access-2016

How do I export:

1. Data
2. Tables
3. Query tables
4. Forms

from Access 2016 
[the file type/extension of this version seems different than older versions - hence the difficulties]

into SQL Server? [ preferably SQL Server 2016 (LocalDb)]

When I try using SQL Server 2016 Management Studio as in:

```
Select Database -> Right Click -> import
```

it only allows `*.mdb` databases and my access database is `*.accdb`

If I try to save my database as an earlier version of access it tells me there features in my database that are not compatible with earlier versions of Access

Comment: You cannot import forms.